# Multicoloured vertical lines on booting

Tags: drivers, graphics, display, screen

After I boot my machine, the screen shows different multicoloured lines which disappear after some time.

The lines are vertical.

I am looking for a permanent solution to this problem. I am attaching the configuration here:

[image: configuration]

Comment: This happens on some hardware with some kernel revisions. That's not a real problem.

Comment: Can you suggest a workaround @Pilot6